# how to compare substring in a list and fetch the whole string if its present using python

Tags: python

I have a list containing strings

```
 list=["geeks for geeks","string1","string2","geeks"]
```

I want to check if "geek" is present in the list, if present fetch me the whole string from the list

if geek in list:

```
output :
    geeks for geeks
    geeks
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: you have asked many questions over your time on Stack Overflow, but have not accepted any answers. If you feel one of the answers to this question (or others) has answered your question, it is good etiquette to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the Python reserved word `list` with another variable name like `lis` or `words`. You can try this

```
lis = ["geeks for geeks", "string1", "string2", "geeks"]
for word in lis:
    if "geek" in word:
        print(word)
```

The output is

```
geeks for geeks
geeks
```

Or if you want to append to a new list

```
words = []
for word in lis:
    if "geek" in word:
        words.append(word)
print(words)
```

Or using list comprehension (thanks @Chris!)

```
[word for word in lis if "geek" in word]
```

The output is a list

```
['geeks for geeks', 'geeks']
```

Comment: You may wish to properly name that "1-liner" as a "list comprehension" so that the OP can know what to research.

Comment: thanks @Chris.. you're a "Copy Editor" (gold badge) so you could have edited my answer also, why did you stop doing so after 500? haha i'm just curious

Comment: I didn't. I've edited 1,269 posts. So far.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a list comprehension.

```
lst = ["geeks for geeks", "string1", "string2", "geeks"]
lst2 = [s for s in lst if "geek" in s]
# ['geeks for geeks', 'geeks']
```

You may wish to use `str.lower` to account for different capitalizations of "geek".

```
lst2 = [s for s in lst if "geek" in s.lower()]
```